# JavaFX2: Consume Restful services

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, javafx-2

I am trying to work on an architecture to consume RESTFul services from a JavaFX application. The requirement is to use spring's rest template(Not too pressed for this. If spring does not work then probably I can look at jersey or resteasy.

My setup is as below:

My main class has a dropdown listing values from a RESTFul service.

The architecture to hit the RESTFul services is as below:

1. I have a client class that gives me the instance of the service class that hits the rest services.
2. In the service class, I have various methods that I hit on the RESTFul service.

   ```
   public MyService1()
   {
       AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
           MyConfig.class);
       context.registerShutdownHook();
   }

   @Autowired
   private RestOperations restTemplate;

   private final Logger   LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService1.class);

   public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() throws IOException
   {
       HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>>>(
           createParts(), createMultiPartHeaders());

       Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();

       List<MyObject> myObjects = restTemplate.getForObject(
           "http://localhost:8080/my-webservices/objects", List.class, vars);

       return myObjects;
   }
   ```

With the above setup, I get the exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have not added the dependency library containing "BeanCreationException" class. Please add the jar file of spring as dependency for that JavaFX Project.